# Why does $\operatorname{Im}\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}+i x\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh(\pi x)$, and what can be said of the real part?

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function, digamma-function

Wikipedia [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Special_values) that

$$\operatorname{Im}\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}+i x\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh(\pi x),$$

where $\psi$ is the digamma function.

1. How can we prove this identity?
2. Does a similar identity hold for $\operatorname{Re}\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}+i x\right)$?

Wikipedia claims the above identity can be derived by "taking the logarithmic derivative of $\left|\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+i x\right)\right|^2$, which I can almost see*, but I'm not sure how to handle taking derivatives of complex absolute values.

---

*based on the identity $\left|\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+i x\right)\right|^2=\frac{\pi}{\cosh(\pi x)},$ found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General).

Comment: You could use the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the digamma function in combination with the [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can we prove this identity?

Since
$$
\psi \left( x \right) -\psi \left( 1-x \right) =\left( \ln \left( \Gamma \left( x \right) \Gamma \left( 1-x \right) \right) \right) ^\prime
$$
we have
$$
\text{Im}\psi \left( \frac{1}{2}+ix \right) =\frac{1}{2}\left[ \psi \left( \frac{1}{2}+ix \right) -\psi \left( \frac{1}{2}-ix \right) \right] =\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh \pi x
$$

> Does a similar identity hold for $\operatorname{Re}\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}+i x\right)$?

I didn't find a nice representation of this one.

Comment: Thanks, this explanation of part 1 makes sense to me. I’m just going to wait a bit and see if someone has anything else to add about $\operatorname{Re}\psi(1/2+i x)$ before accepting.